# How to show 'list of reviews' on product detail page?

Tags: magento-1.9, review, ratings

How can I show a detailed list of respective product reviews at the end of product detail pages? I used this code at `view.phtml`

```
<?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it is showing only short summary (like number of reviews) instead of detailed review summary.

I mm using the RWD theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the answer for my question. :)

**Step1**  add this code on `local.xml`

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
                <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
                    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                        <label>Review Form Fields Before</label>
                        <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
                        <action method="setElementClass"><value>rewards</value></action>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

**Step2**  Call it from `view.phtml`

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('reviews') ?>`

Maybe it will be helpful for upcoming newbies like me in the future :)

*Source* `https://gist.github.com/bekapod/5395583`